# Papaya viewer - how to import and use in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, papaya

I've been tasked with implementing Papaya viewer in a React frontend, and it's my first time working with it. It might sound silly, but I can't figure out how to import it and get it to run in React.

I've installed it from NPM ([NPM Link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/papaya-viewer)) and tried to implement it using the examples provided, but nothing renders on screen . In the console, I can see the following error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: PAPAYA_MANGO_INSTALLED is not defined
> at main.js:1553:1

This is my React component:

```
import Papaya from "papaya-viewer";
import "../../components/papaya/papaya.css";

const QC = () => {
const params = [];
params["worldSpace"] = true;
params["images"] = ["./sub-OAS30007_ses-d1641_run-01_T1w.nii.gz"];
params["surfaces"] = [];



    return (
        <div className={"papaya"} data-params={"params"}>
        </div>
    )
}

export default QC;
```

Has anybody successfully implemented it in React and can share some starter code? Many thanks.

Comment: This thread (https://github.com/rii-mango/Papaya/issues/90) and especially this may help: https://github.com/arindas/papaya-react